# Convert multiple json object into array of object in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

My data is currently stored in this format:

```
{
   "label":["X","Y"],
   "data":{
      "site1":{
         "week":[
            {
               "idWeek":"9",
               "max":2,
               "min":0
            }
         ]
      },
      "site2":{
         "week":[
            {
               "idWeek":"9",
               "max":2,
               "min":0
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

And I need to convert it into this format:

```
{
   "label":["X","Y"],
   "myClient":{
      "week":[
         {
            "id":"9",
            "access":2,
            "lost":0
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

As you can see, I also need to take the keys (site name) and I need remove "data" and change name of property.

Any ideas on how I can do this in Java (I'm using Java 8 with Spring Boot? I'm not very good at restructuring that type of data.

**UPDATE**

My solutions: I did different interfaces and I used RestTemplate! I don't know it's the best solution however it worked.

```
public Optional<Consolidate> getCasosPorEstado() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<Consolidate> res = restTemplate.exchange(PATH_CONSOLIDATE, HttpMethod.GET, null,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<Consolidate>() {
            });

    return Optional.of(res.getBody());
}


@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "label", "data" })
@Data
public class Consolidate {

    @JsonProperty("label")
    private List<String> labels = null;

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private MyClient client;    

}

@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "site1" })
class MyClient {
    @JsonProperty("Site")
    Site SiteObject;    
}   


@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "week" })
class MS {
    @JsonProperty("week")
    private List<Week> week = null;
}


@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Semana {
    @JsonAlias("idWeek")
    private String id;

    @JsonAlias("max")
    private Double access;

    @JsonAlias("min")
    private Double lost;

}
```

Comment: Do you need to keep `"site2"` data after reformatting?  Do you use any POJOs to serialize/deserialize the JSON or you use plain maps/lists?

Comment: Yes, I will keep use "site2" after reformatting and I try use RestTemplate and ObjectMapper!